# Why apache tika with parseToString returns extra new line character at the end of the string?

Tags: java, newline, apache-tika

Important parts of my code:

```
import org.apache.tika.Tika;

Tika tika;

"test".getBytes() // <-- contains array of 4 bytes

tika.parseToString(TikaInputStream.get("test".getBytes())) // <-- will return 5 bytes with newline /n
```

Why it is so and can Tika return only the original number of bytes without a newline?

It looks like a bug in a Tika that needs to be fixed.

Is there any easy short solution to do this without removing the newline after parsing on my own or without using some content handlers? The documentation for Tika didn't help me.

(I suppose my content to parse will have a lot of new line characters that I want to keep even at the end and I cannot be sure if Tika will add this character always at the end or just for some kind of input)

Comment: You are asking Apache Tika to convert your input into plain text, identifying the file type, running parsing over it etc. Why would you expect to get the same thing back?

Comment: If the file has content A why Tika will not extract content A but A+'\n'? (it is unexpected and not documented behavior)  Why there is no option to omit a blank new line after the parsing process? What is the purpose of a new line character from the Tika parse process? I understand it can be complicated with files, but it even cannot handle 4 bytes to not add something own to the original input (it changes the original input, it is not the same on the output). Why would I expect to get the same thing back? And why not? Why not use some random string utils instead?

Comment: Hand Tika a PDF or an Image and you're explicitly not expecting the same bytes back! If you ask Tika for the XHTML version you'll see the wrapping `<p>` tags that give the newline

Comment: I see ... you're right, I forgot it while doing integration tests. The Aim of Apache Tika is the extraction of files and I should not expect the same bytes back, now I understand the concept, thank you. The example I posted here is not a common use case for Tika processing and its behavior is therefore OK.